# Ignore Filter on Visual

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to ignore master Filter on this measure can anybody help me out

I'm not talking about edit Interaction. I'm talking about the filter on the page. How can I ignore it?

Here is my measure:

```
alhumaydani% =
VAR _sales =
    DIVIDE (
        CALCULATE (
            COUNT ( 'ROUND 2 Survey Productivity Data'[row.__created.1] ),
            'ROUND 2 Survey Productivity Data'[row.username] = "alhumaydani"
        ),
        COUNT ( 'ROUND 2 Survey Productivity Data'[row.username] )
    )
RETURN
    IF ( ISBLANK ( _sales ), 0, _sales )
```

This should be 24% but it's giving me 100%.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be out of the scope of the selection, you can count the selected rows or you can do it based on all

of Dominator of your divide is:

```
COUNTROWS (ALLSELECTED('ROUND 2 Survey Productivity Data'))
```

or

```
COUNTROWS (ALL('ROUND 2 Survey Productivity Data'))
```